# jQuery fade flickers

Tags: jquery, hover, fadein, fade, fadeout

I have jQuery fade going here: http://dougie.thewestharbour.com/

When you hover over the .main-overlay div I would like it to fade out then when you take your mouse off of it, I would like it to fade back in.

However, you can see it's just flickering right now. I'm guessing it's because the div disappears so it's treated as a mouseout when it's faded out but I'm not sure how to go about solving it.

Here is my javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {


    $('.main-overlay').hover(

        //Mouseover, fadeIn the hidden hover class 
        function() {

            $(this).fadeOut('1000');

        },

        //Mouseout, fadeOut the hover class
        function() {

            $(this).fadeIn('1000');   

    }).click (function () {

        //Add selected class if user clicked on it
        $(this).addClass('selected');

    });

});
```

And here is one of the items that the overlay div is attached to:

```
<li><div class="main-overlay"></div><span class="caption">The store front</span><img src="http://dougie.thewestharbour.com/wp-content/uploads/store-front.jpg" alt="store front" title="store-front" width="730" height="360" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-98" /></li>
```

Thanks,

Wade

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's happening because `fadeOut` has a `display:none` at the end of it, so when you move your mouse after the `fadeOut` has completed it will trigger the unhover function.  Instead, just `animate` the `opacity`:

```
$('.main-overlay').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({opacity: 0}, 1000);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
})
```

[Example →](http://jsfiddle.net/nV2yA/1/)

Comment: I like that solution a lot! But won't the element then stay visible, possibly covering things in the background that it shouldn't be covering?

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer mentions, `fadeOut` sets `display:none` at the end, so the element no longer affects the layout of the page.  The suggestion to just animate the opacity is correct, but there is already a function for doing so, `fadeTo`, which is a wee bit cleaner than writing the animation yourself:

```
$('.main-overlay').hover(
    //Mouseover, fadeIn the hidden hover class 
    function() {
        $(this).fadeTo(0,1000);
    },
   //Mouseout, fadeOut the hover class
    function() {
        $(this).fadeTo(1,1000);   
})
```

Comment: While this solution works (and is certainly cleaner than using `animate`), the fadeTo method is actually `.fadeTo( duration, opacity [, complete ] )`.

So the above should be FadeIn: `fadeTo(1000, 0)` and FadeOut: `fadeTo(1000, 1)`. Good solution all that being said.